# Filling of a structure using memcpy

Tags: c, struct, memcpy

This is my code. I thought I will be getting a SegFault on `b2->x.pointer1->data` because I didn't `malloc` the `b2->x.pointer1`. Can anybody please give me some explanation to it? What values were copied to `b2->x.pointer1` while doing memcpy? And also regarding the book-keeping of `struct *b2` particularly which was filled by `memcpy`, that how it kept a record of its members? All my motive is to know that how `b2->x.pointer1` got its memory on heap.

```
struct A
{
    int data;
};


struct B
{
    int data;
    union X
    {
        struct A *pointer1;
        //another
    }x;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    struct B *b1 = (struct B*) malloc(sizeof(struct B));
    b1->data = 100;
    b1->x.pointer1 = (struct A*) malloc(sizeof(struct A));
    b1->x.pointer1->data = 1;

    struct B *b2 = (struct B*) malloc(sizeof(struct B));
    //b2->x.pointer1 = (struct A*) malloc(sizeof(struct A));

    memcpy(b2, b1, sizeof(struct B));

    printf("%d", b2->x.pointer1->data);

    return 0;
}
```

And what if I'll `free(b1)`? Will it free the `b1->x.pointer1` too or will there be some memory leak here?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks for the link. But I'm bounded by my compiler. It reports errors, if I don't cast the return from malloc().

Comment: ....'cause you are using a [tag:c++] compiler to compile [tag:c] code...

Comment: ...and which is bad.

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks IDE with MinGW suite. Most likely, it's using c++ compiler for the compilation. But I don't know.

Comment: The toolchain setup points to the gcc compiler too. Even my source file has extension .c . But why compilation is happening under c++ compiler, I don't know.

Comment: are you including the right header files?

Comment: @ChrisTurner hadn't included the `stdlib.h`. :p Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `free` function doesn't know anything about the content of the memory being freed.

In other words `free(b1)` will simply free the memory `b1` points to, resulting in a memory leak because `b1->x.pointer1` has not been freed and cannot be accessed anymore.

You need to free `b1->x.pointer1` explicitly *before* freeing `b1`.

Correct sequence for freeing:

```
free(b1->x.pointer1);
free(b1);
free(b2);
```

The rule of thumb is: everything that has been allocated by `malloc` needs explicitely to be freed with `free`.

Concerning `b2`: after the `memcpy`, the content of `*b2` is *exactly the same* as the content of `*b1`, so `b2->x.pointer1` points to the *exact same* location as `b1->x.pointer1`, therefore `free(b2->x.pointer1);` must not be done once `free(b1->x.pointer1);` has been done. Freeing twice the same memory results in undefined behaviour (most likely a crash).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Michael Walz's answer...

> Can anybody please give me some explanation to it?

`memcpy` does a bit by bit copy of the specified number of bytes. That's why you don't segfault. If you go down and look in the memory, you will find that the bits in `b2` have become exactly same as `b1`.

> What values were copied to b2->x.pointer1 while doing memcpy?

The data copied will be same as source (`b1` in this case) from where you are copying. For the computer, `b1` and `b2` are just two different locations which have the same bit pattern.